# How can I obtain the cube root in C++?

Tags: c++

I know how to obtain the *square root* of a number using the `sqrt` function.

How can I obtain the *cube root* of a number?

Comment: You mean the cube root, not the "square root with root 3".

Comment: You can use pow(), with the power 1/3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463486/cube-root-of-a-number

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269069/finding-cube-root-in-c

Comment: -1: This question was better before. Now it's awful. "please guide me to overload sqrt operator" How about we guide you in creating SO questions?

Comment: @Kotte 1/3 in C/C++ is 0, not one third.

Comment: @OrangeDog true, 1.0/3.0 is more clear

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it was rolled back again

Comment: @JanDvorak: Fixed. Not sure why the OP is being so stubborn.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit edit war alert

Comment: @Jan: Please flag if you see it happen again.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I almost rolled your edit back myself.  Your's is a *very* different, albeit far more reasonable, question.  Since it's been answered before, I believe it should be left-as is, and left closed.

Comment: @RichardSitze: Firstly, no, that's _precisely_ what the OP is trying to ask. Read all the comments (and unfortunately you missed his first draft, due to the grace period, but it was a lot clearer). Secondly, has it really been answeed before? Feel free to suggest a duplicate, but neither of the linked questions are that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [finding cube root in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269069/finding-cube-root-in-c)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`sqrt` stands for "square root", and "square root" means raising to the power of `1/2`. There is no such thing as "square root with root 2", or "square root with root 3". For [other roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root), you change the first word; **in your case, you are seeking how to perform *cube rooting***.

Before C++11, there is no specific function for this, but you can go back to first principles:

- Square root: `std::pow(n, 1/2.)` (or [`std::sqrt(n)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt))
- Cube root: `std::pow(n, 1/3.)` (or [`std::cbrt(n)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/cbrt) since C++11)
- Fourth root: `std::pow(n, 1/4.)`
- *etc.*

---

If you're expecting to pass negative values for `n`, avoid the `std::pow` solution — [it doesn't support negative inputs with fractional exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4269119/560648), and this is why `std::cbrt` was added:

```
std::cout << std::pow(-8, 1/3.) << '\n';  // Output: -nan
std::cout << std::cbrt(-8)      << '\n';  // Output: -2
```

---

<sup>N.B. That `.` is really important, because otherwise `1/3` uses integer division and results in `0`.</sup>

Comment: I mean Sqrt not square,for example sqrt(4)=2;

Comment: @HavaDarabi: I don't understand. `sqrt` stands for "square root" whether you like it or not, and `sqrt(4)` _is_ `2`.

Comment: See the [this already referenced SO q&a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269069/finding-cube-root-in-c) - a solution based on `pow` does not find the cube-root for negative numbers.  It's good to reference the C++11 solution.  Net: -1/+1

Comment: @RichardSitze: `std::cbrt(-8)` results in `-2`. That's why they added it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's not the standard library solution that's the problem, it's the `pow' based solution.

Comment: Ty for editing your question to include this critical detail.

Comment: Thank you for noting that the decimal is critical. Without it everything was coming out to 1.

Comment: WARNING: using pow(n, 1/x.) will not calculate the exact value in every case. I prefer to avoid using this technique if possible.

Comment: @DonLarry When pow(n, 1/x.) will fail? What other techniques are available?

Answer (score 8):

in C++11 `std::cbrt` was introduced as part of **math** library, you may [refer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/cbrt)

Answer (score 2):

```
include <cmath>
std::pow(n, 1./3.)
```

Also, in C++11 there is `cbrt` in the same header.

[Math for Dummies](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-convert-square-roots-to-exponents0.html).

Comment: I suspect this readily fails for negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The nth root of x is equal to x^(1/n), so use `std::pow`. But I don't see what this has to with operator overloading.

Comment: @Hava: `sqrt` is not an "operator", and you cannot "overload" it to perform a different thing with the same arguments. Your terminology is all wrong.

Comment: @HavaDarabi no, you don't

Answer (score 0):

Just to point this out, though we can use both ways but

```
 long long res = pow(1e9, 1.0/3);
 long long res2 = cbrt(1e9);
 cout<<res<<endl;
 cout<<res2<<endl;
```

returns

```
999
1000
```

So, in order to get the correct results with pow function we need to add an offset of 0.5 with the actual number or use a double data type i.e.

```
long long res = pow(1e9+0.5, 1.0/3)
double res = pow(1e9, 1.0/3)
```

more detailed explanation here [C++ pow unusual type conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187956/c-pow-unusual-type-conversion)

Comment: I wouldn't trust `cbrt` to perform precise calculations as well.

Comment: Ideally yes, we should do the rounding ourselves, we can simply use double or add an offset as I have pointed out in the answer. Thanks for pointing out :D

Answer (score -1):

Actually the round must go for the above solutions to work.

**The Correct solution would be**

ans  =  round(pow(n, 1./3.));

Answer (score -1):

The solution for this problem is

```
cube_root = pow(n,(float)1/3);
```

and you should `#include <math.h>` library file

**Older standards of C/C++ don't support cbrt() function.**

When we write code like `cube_root = pow(n,1/3);` the compiler thinks `1/3 = 0` (division problem in C/C++), so you need to do typecasting using `(float)1/3` in order to get the correct answer

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
float n = 64 , cube_root ;
clrscr();
cube_root = pow(n , (float)1/3);
cout<<"cube root = "<<cube_root<<endl;
getch();
return 0;
}
```

cube root = 4

Comment: Turbo C is not a C compiler, and Turbo C++ is not a C++ compiler. They both predate the first C standard (C89) and C++ standard (C++98) by a long time and **aren't valid C or C++ compilers**. Turbo C++ is more than a decade older than C++98 so your code **doesn't even compile in C++ compilers** (there's no iostream.h for you). Besides there's no language called C/C++, they're very different languages and both Turbo products are also different

Comment: `cbrt` is a new function in C++11 so even compliant C++98 compilers don't support it, let alone a non-C++ compiler

Comment: Why use `float` division and then call a `double` function?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this C algorithm :

```c
// return a number that, when multiplied by itself twice, makes N. 
unsigned cube_root(unsigned n){
    unsigned a = 0, b;
    for (int c = sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT / 3 * 3 ; c >= 0; c -= 3) {
        a <<= 1;
        b = 3 * a * (a + 1) + 1;
        if (n >> c >= b)
            n -= b << c, ++a;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would discourage any of the above methods as they didn't work for me. I did pow(64, 1/3.) along with pow(64, 1./3.) but the answer I got was 3        
**Here's my logic.**

```
ans = pow(n, 1/3.);
if (pow(ans, 3) != n){
   ans++;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. For example for the cube root of 7 this will return 2.9129... instead of 1.9129... which is off by merely just ~52.2%