# pow(a,b) returning 1 less than the actual value when b is more than 15?

Tags: c++, c, pow

```
    int n = 15;
    unsigned long long int s,a;
    s=pow(10,n) + 2;
    a=1000000000000000+2;
    cout<<s<<endl;
    cout<<a;
```

here the output is `10000000000000001` and `1000000000000002` how is this even possible.I am using code blocks on windows 64 bit.

Comment: This is one issue of using pow with integers

Comment: @Fredrik it does in my system

Comment: @Fredrik there's no problem at all with that code, automatic conversion from integer to float/double takes care of it. You could enable warnings for automatic conversion `-Wconversion` in GCC/clang, but the normal behavior is to just do the conversion.

Comment: @Fredrik To be fair, `-Wconversion` is a fairly uncommon flag. It's not included in `-Wall` nor `-Wextra`.

Comment: To be clear, the erroneous outputs you've shown are for `n=16` (as indicated by the title) and not `n=15`, as you've shown in your code.  `1000000000000001` (16 digits) is exactly representable as a double.  `10000000000000001` (17 digits) is not - the closest doubles are `10000000000000000` and `10000000000000002`.

Comment: duplicates: [Why pow(10,5) = 9,999 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9704195/995714), [Why does pow(5,2) become 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22264236/995714), [Why does pow(n,2) return 24 when n=5, with my compiler and OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25678481/995714)...