# How to fix E2015 "ambiguity between pow(double,double) and pow(float,int)"

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

I'm doing my homework in C++ Builder 6.

When I try to get a cubic root from variable X, I get this error:

```
result = std::pow(x, 1.0 / 3);
```

> E2015 Ambiguity between "std::pow(double,double)" and "std::pow(float, int)"

What should i do to fix this? Or may be there is another way to get a cubic root?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I obtain the cube root in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103769/how-can-i-obtain-the-cube-root-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Declare variable `x` as `double` instead of float.
2. `std:pow(double(x), 1.0/3)`

Answer (score 0):

The **std::cbrt()** is an inbuilt function in C++ STL which is used to calculate the cube root of number.
It accepts a number as argument and returns the cube root of that number.

result = std::cbrt(x);

Comment: C++ Builder 6 is like 10 years off... And `cbrt` is C++11.

Comment: the question is why using such an ancient compiler?

Comment: Because my teacher said me to do some first works in C++ Builder

Comment: is standard in C++11, what about cbrt() in cmath